# Anchoring/Positioning of labels in scrollview

Tags: ios, resize, interface-builder, positioning

I'm trying to get the layout below to resize correctly in landscape. It looks as it does in IB in portrait mode, but when I rotate to landscape I lose the 'Sources' label and the bottom textview. All of them are anchored to all sides and set to resize horizontally and vertically in the parent scrollview.

[image: Problematic anchoring]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got around this by removing the child UITextViews from the parent UIScrollView.